# Having trouble with percentages and calculating interest

Tags: java

Include one additional user input, the percentage by which the extra contribution should be increased each year.  For example, suppose the user wants tocontribute$1000 the first year, with a 2% annual increase.  At the end of year 1,$1000 would be added to the account.  At the end of year 2, the extra amount grows by 2%, so$1020 would be added to the account.   At the end of year  3,  the extra amount grows by another  2%  so $1040.40 would be added to the account, etc.
I'm having trouble with the attached code, can anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GettingRichSlowly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get user input for initial deposit, annual interest rate,
        //  number of years, amount of yearly extra contribution
        System.out.println("Enter initial deposit: ");
        double initialDeposit = scnr.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter annual interest rate (as a percentage): ");
        double interestRate = scnr.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter number of years: ");
        int years = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How much extra would you like to contribute at the end of each year? ");
        double extraAmount = scnr.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How much should the annual contribution increase each year (as a percentage)?");
        double annualIncrease = scnr.nextDouble();
        annualIncrease = annualIncrease / 100 + 1;

        // Amount in the account at the beginning of the current year
        double yearStart = initialDeposit;

        // Repeat years number of times
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= years) {
            // Dollar amount of interest earned during the current year
            double interest = yearStart * interestRate / 100;

            if (i == 1) {
            double yearEnd = yearStart + interest + extraAmount;
            }
            else {
                 extraAmount = extraAmount * annualIncrease;
                double yearEnd = yearStart + interest + extraAmount;
            }

            // Show the results for the current year
            System.out.format("%3d\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\n", i, yearStart, interest, extraAmount, yearEnd);

            // Update yearStart for the following year
            yearStart = yearEnd;

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

edit: there are several error messages I get when running this code with the input 100, 7.5, 10, 1000, 5.
GettingRichSlowly.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable yearEnd
location: class GettingRichSlowly
System.out.format("%3d\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\n", i, yearStart, interest, extraAmount, yearEnd);
^
GettingRichSlowly.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable yearEnd
location: class GettingRichSlowly
yearStart = yearEnd;
What do these mean?

Comment: By the way, never use `double`/`Double` or `float`/`Float` for money, where you need [accurate results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Use only `BigDecimal` or integers.

Comment: Or a `long` representing the cents.

Comment: I do not see what is wrong - what do you expect?  please show figures, did you think of interest of interest in 2nd year?
E. g. interestRate  5 [%]
initialDeposit 1000 [e. g. $]
extraAmount 500 [e. g. $]
annualIncrease 2 [%]
what would you expect and what you get?

Comment: The body within the `if (i == 1)` statement is duplicated within the `else` clause. This if-else can be rewritten to `if (i != 1) { extraAmount = extraAmount * annualIncrease; } double yearEnd = yearStart + interest + extraAmount;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare "double yearEnd" beyond if body.

```
       double yearEnd;
        if (i == 1) {
            yearEnd = yearStart + interest + extraAmount;
        }
        else {
            extraAmount = extraAmount * annualIncrease;
            yearEnd = yearStart + interest + extraAmount;
        }

        // Show the results for the current year
        System.out.format("%3d\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\t$%12.2f\n", i, yearStart, interest, extraAmount, yearEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks! When I inputted this, it gave me this error: GettingRichSlowly.java:2: class, interface, or enum expected
Simulates the growth of money in an account that pays interest. Do you know what this means?

Comment: is it your whole program or do you use GettingRichSlowly class in other program?